# A Função .load da Biblioteca Jquery não está funcionando!

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

```js
<script>
$(".coment").load("coments.php #coments");
</script>
```

Essa função faz com que ele carregue os comentários após enviar o mesmo! Assim faz com que o comentário seja enviado ao mesmo tempo e visualizado!

Só que quando eu coloquei esse código para visualizar os comentários, ele não está carregando nenhum comentário! Verifiquei se é a div, se é o "class" se é o "id" mas nenhum vai! Preciso de ajuda!

Comment: Daniel, bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow. Peço que edite sua questão e adicione o código completo da página html que faz a requisição, bem como do script coments.php para que possamos te auxiliar da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo trecho de código provido pode ser que você não tenha esperado a página ser carregada. Tente usar o método `ready` (https://api.jquery.com/ready/):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function()
               {
                  $(".coment").load("coments.php #coments");
               }
      );
 </script>
```

Comment: Mesmo assim não vai cara! Nem a função ele está chamando! Deve haver alguma coisa que deve estar entrando em conflito com a biblioteca, e não tá deixa iniciar a função, algo assim! Deve ser...

Comment: Então pode ser uma infinidade de coisas. Como o @Bruno Bermann comentou em sua pergunta, pode ser que você : 1) Não esteja com o jQuery instalado (verifique se `jQuery` não é nulo), 2) a sua página `coments.php` não existe , 3) o elemento `#coments` não existe na página ou não está sendo renderizado, etc.  Forneça mais evidência para que possamos ajudá-lo!

Comment: Gente, eu achei o problema, eu estava fazendo esse código acima do **<script src="jquery.min.js"></scrtipt>** Ou seja, ele estava puxando uma função que ele não entendia, porque estava acima da Biblioteca. E ele não estava reconhecendo ...